# What is the difference between parent and base in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, subclass, pragma

There appears to be a new pragma named [`parent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/parent/lib/parent.pm) that does roughly the same thing as [`base`](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html).  What does `parent` do that warrants a new (non-core) module?  I am missing something?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`base` tried to do one too many things – automatically handling loading modules but also allowing establishing inheritance from classes already loaded (possibly from a file whose name wasn't based on the module name).  To sort of make it work, there was some hackery that caused surprising results in some cases.  Rather than break backwards compatibility, a new, replacement pragma `parent` was introduced with cleaner semantics.

`parent` will be a core module as of 5.10.1.

**Update:** forgot that `base` handles `fields` (if you are using the `fields` pragma), which `parent` doesn't do.

Comment: Also, compare perl -wE'say require base' to perl -wE'say require parent'

Comment: I happen to come back to this page to look up the answer over and over again. Mnemonic: `base` and `parent` appeared in alphabetical order.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer unlike fatal and autodie :)

Comment: @ysth in perl 5.26 those both print 1, what was the old outputs 10 years ago?

Comment: @cat looks like it was changed in 2016.  https://metacpan.org/diff/file?target=CORION/parent-0.235/&source=CORION%2Fparent-0.234#lib/parent.pm

Comment: @cat `> perl5.14.1 -wE 'say require parent'
All your base are belong to us
> perl5.14.1 -wE 'say require base'
1`

Answer (score 43):

Armed with the extra bit of information from ysth, I was able to see the differences in the docs:

The [`base`](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html) pragma does the following things:

- adds the named package to `@ISA`
- loads the module with the same name as the named package using [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) (unless it detects that the package has already been loaded)
- won't fail if a module with the same name as the package doesn't exist
- dies if there are no symbols in the named package
- if `$VERSION` does not exist in named package, base sets it to `"-1, set by base.pm"`
- initializes the [`fields`](http://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html) of the named package if they exist
- does not call the import function of the named package

The [`parent`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/parent/lib/parent.pm) pragma does the following things:

- adds the named package to `@ISA`
- loads the module with the same name as the named package using `require`
- accepts an option that tells it not to die if a module with the same name as the package doesn't exist

Comment: Almost.  The norequire option just tells it not to do the require (so the class must already be loaded).  This means it doesn't have to trap errors and decide whether they should be suppressed or not.